# How do I understand the warnings from rbind?

Tags: r, rbind

If I have two data.frames with the same column names, I can use rbind to make a single data frame.  However, if I have one is a factor and the other is an int, I get a warning like this:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 1L, 0L,
>   0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

The following is a simplification of the problem:

```
t1 <- structure(list(test = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("False", "True"), class = "factor")), .Names = "test", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
t2 <- structure(list(test = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
)), .Names = "test", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
rbind(t1, t2)
```

With the single column, this is easy to understand, but when it is part of a dozen or more factors, it can be difficult.  What is there about the warning message to tell me which column to look at?  Barring that, what is a good technique to understand which column is in error?

Comment: `class(t1$test)` is `factor` and `class(t2$test)` is `integer`. Try to turn `t2$test` into factor too.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  If this is part of a larger structure, how do I know it is the "test" column?  I originally found this with 18 columns and want to know how to simply figure out which column to turn into a factor.

Comment: You need to compare `sapply(t1, class)` and `sapply(t2, class)` I guess, if `t1` and `t2` have the same number of columns and the same column names.

Comment: @Pascal - you might want to sort the column names before `sapply`-ing too. `rbind` can handle names that are out of order, but the comparison will then be not aligned - e.g.: `sapply(one[sort(colnames(one))],class)`

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, sorry for not taking time to elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could knock up a simple little comparison script using `class` and `mapply`, to compare where the `rbind` will break down due to non-matching data types, e.g.:

```
one <- data.frame(a=1,b=factor(1))
two <- data.frame(b=2,a=2)

common <- intersect(names(one),names(two))
mapply(function(x,y) class(x)==class(y), one[common], two[common])

#    a     b 
# TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This would be a great message enhance for rbind, could you submit it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on thelatemail's answer, here is a function to compare two data.frames for rbinding:

```
mergeCompare <- function(one, two) {
  cat("Distinct items: ", setdiff(names(one),names(two)), setdiff(names(two),names(one)), "\n")
  print("Non-matching items:")
  common <- intersect(names(one),names(two))
  print (mapply(function(x,y) {class(x)!=class(y)}, one[common], two[common]))
}
```