# testing for identical factor levels in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, logic

I have two large data.frames and want to rbind them together. When I do... I get the following error message:

> ```
> 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(10, 5, 5, 8, 9, 3, 5, 2,  :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(11420, 10469, 7090, 10009,  :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> ```

So I wanted to create a test to see whether the columns in each data frame have the same factor levels. Column 1 of data.frame 1 should have the same levels as column 1 of data.frame 2... etc.

Here is what I wrote...

```
for (i in 1:ncol(frame1)) 
{if(is.factor(frame1[,i])==TRUE|is.ordered(frame1[,i]==TRUE))
{levels(frame[,i])==levels(frame2[,i])}
else {print("not.Factor")}}
```

When I run this, I see error messages:

> ```
> 15: In levels(ordinalRecipients[, i]) == levels(last.recipients.cohort[,  ... :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

These two data.frames are of unequal length, but is there a way I can still identify whether the factor levels for each column are equal? Thank-you for your help.

Comment: R should be able to handle this out of the box, e.g.: `dat1 <- data.frame(id=1:3,var=letters[1:3]);dat2 <- data.frame(id=4:6,var=letters[2:4]);rbind(dat1,dat2)` Can you provide your code and **simplified** versions of your `frame1/2` where it fails?

Comment: Thanks for your help. One of the columns where NA is generated is a column of zip codes. It should not have been encoded as a factor in the first place, so that took care of one of the issues. The other I'm still looking for and will get back to you.

Comment: Figured it out, the remaining problem, a column in data.frame 1 was a factor and the column in the data.frame 2 was numeric. For the sake of learning, how would you program to test whether the factor levels from two different columns from two different data.frames were equal?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825314/how-do-i-understand-the-warnings-from-rbind/28825739 , but comparing `levels` instead of `class`

Comment: Very cool, thank you very much.